Record change broke the application
We have a database application that had a record changed in one table [RPI] that was referenced by another table [ERP] and now the entire application won't move forward or load anything from the RPI table related to the ERP table.
Is editing the record directly in the table to reference the old record in the RPI the correct way to approach this, or is there a better way?
I should mention that there is no dev environment to test anything and any changes are made directly to production tables :/
